# Including external jars after launching Pyspark in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jar, pyspark, jupyter

I have been trying in vain to include external jars into pyspark/Jupyter notebook env after the notebook has been launched. (Alternatively, the jars are included successfully either with:
1. Use --jar ojdbc6.jar
2. include the jar in spark-defaults.conf )

I have tried below all failed:

Idea 1:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("testjars") \
        .config("spark.jars", "C:\\Users\\U620311\\ojdbc6.jar") \
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:\\Users\\U620311\\ojdbc6.jar") \
        .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "C:\\Users\\U620311\\ojdbc6.jar") \
       .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

Invoke jar file as below:

```
DB_USER = "" 
DB_PASS = "" 
DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
JDBC_URL = "<connection string>" 
query = '''(select * from <tablename>) t1'''
ojdbcDF = (sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", DB_DRIVER).option("url", JDBC_URL).option("dbtable", query).option("user", DB_USER).option("password", DB_PASS).load())
```

Idea 2:

I have played with all permutations. Include extraclasspath but not spark.jars and vice versa. no success.

Idea 3:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars ojdbc6.jar pyspark-shell'
import pyspark
sc.stop()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

DB_USER = "<uid>" 
DB_PASS = "<pwd>" 
DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
JDBC_URL = "<connection string>" 
query = '''(select * from <tablename>) t1'''
ojdbcDF = (sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", DB_DRIVER).option("url", JDBC_URL).option("dbtable", query).option("user", DB_USER).option("password", DB_PASS).load())
```

All of the above lead to the same error message. Would you please help in identifying if there is missing configuration or missing code. Please suggest an alternatives to try.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o373.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:78)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```